# Cannot decrease width of flexigrid if desired width is less than initial size

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

Found the following question [here](http://groups.google.com/group/flexigrid/browse_thread/thread/0ed687e4cbb002e5/c36fbcb6ed6b4b0c):

> Hello, I am using flexigrid in my application. There is a problem with
>   the Horizontal resize that I cannot reduce the width less than that
>   initial width that I give to it while making the grid.
>
> You can also see this problem in the "Example 3" on
>   http://flexigrid.info/. Try reducing the width of the grid.

I was having the same problem using flexigrid 1.1 and I found a solution so I thought I would post it.

If anyone has a better solution that does not require editing the plugin let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At line 180 of `flexigrid.js` change this:

```
if (newW > p.defwidth) {
    this.gDiv.style.width = newW + 'px';
    p.width = newW;
}
```

to this:

```
//if (newW > p.defwidth) {
    this.gDiv.style.width = newW + 'px';
    p.width = newW;
//}
```

Commenting out this if statement seems to have done the trick, and I have not seen any adverse side effects.